# Increases physical memory continuously Visual C++ CryptMsgClose and CryptReleaseContext

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

I am using C++ and Visual Studio 2005.

I have a project that memory Increases in a very abnormal. When debug the code I Realized That there are Several parts That Contribute to it. Like this for example:

```
 // has to add crypt32.lib to link
#include <windows.h>
#define MY_ENCODING_TYPE  (PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING)

void memoryUP( const unsigned char *pData, int cData )
{
    HCRYPTMSG  msg  = NULL;
    HCRYPTPROV hProv        = NULL;

    CryptAcquireContext(&hProv,NULL,NULL,PROV_RSA_FULL,0);

    msg = CryptMsgOpenToDecode(MY_ENCODING_TYPE,0,0,hProv,NULL,NULL); 

    if(!(CryptMsgUpdate( msg, pData, cData, TRUE)))
    {
        if(msg != NULL)
        {
            CryptMsgClose(msg);
            msg = NULL;
        }
    }

    if (hProv != NULL)
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv,0);

    if (msg != NULL)
    {
        CryptMsgClose(msg);
        msg = NULL;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyFile myfile = myReadFile("c:\\file.p7s");

    {
        for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
        {
            memoryUP( myfile._data, myfile._length );
        }
    }

    delete myfile;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, the memory goes up continuously "when call CryptMsgUpdate". Am I deallocating wrong?

I tried to use [Memory Leak Detection Enabling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method to detect memory leak but nothing appears:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

and

_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just a wild guess, shouldn't you free resources in inverse order of their acquisition? That is, `CryptMsgClose` should come *before* `CryptReleaseContext`.

Comment: Are you saying your memory usage goes up every time you call memoryUP()?  What happens if you comment out the CryptMsgUpdate() call? - do you still get memory increasing each time?

Comment: why is _CryptMsgClose(msg);_ block called two times?

Comment: @Kerrek SB. the reverse order works, no more memory up. Thanks. how to +1 to you?

Comment: @Nick Shaw, yes. if I comment the memory doesnt up. I solve it deallocating in inverser order. Thanks

Comment: @Kerrek SB. If I want to return HCRYPTMSG  msg. HCRYPTMSG getMSG(...) how to do? I have to pass HCRYPTPROV hProv as param to free after HCRYPTMSG?

Comment: @Boris Treukhov. Good point. Thanks

Comment: @Boris: Good point in principle, though the combined setting to NULL in the OP's code practically means that it'll only get called once.

Comment: @Cobaia: Copy the data out of the resource dependent part and then use it after you clean up. Or even better, use RIAA so you don't have to clean up manually at all.

Comment: @Kerrek Sorry I cannot understand. I tried this but memory up: HCRYPTMSG memoryUP( const unsigned char *pData, int cData, HCRYPTPROV hProv )

Comment: @Cobaia: No, you cannot return a dependent resource from your function if the function also cleans up those resources. You have to either copy the relevant data out into your own variable, or otherwise integrate the function into your larger context where you need the `HCRYPTMSG`.

Comment: @Kerrek "Integrate" means to not use a function and declare everything in the procedural way? Sorry for these questions.

Comment: @kerrek I remove the function and put all in one single method. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to release resources in reverse order of their acquisition:

```
 CryptAcquireContext();

 if (success)
 {
   CryptMsgOpenToDecode();

   if (success)
   {
      CryptMsgClose();
   }
   // else: nothing to close, opening failed

   CryptReleaseContext();
 }
 // else: nothing to release, acquisition failed
```

The deeper nested constructions depend on the outer ones and may lock up resources, so you can only release the prerequisite resources after you've released the dependent ones.

Since you tagged this C++, I would be remiss to mention that those sort of things should be handled with RIAA, and you should make a class that takes responsibility for the resource. As you can see even in this simple example, writing the correct error checking paths very quickly become onerous, so it'd be much better and more modular to have a class that cleans up after itself, which automatically happens in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call CryptMsgClose before CryptReleaseContext.